# Is there a more intelligent way to do this besides a long chain of if statements or switch?

Tags: java, design, abstraction

I'm implementing an IRC bot that receives a message and I'm checking that message to determine which functions to call. Is there a more clever way of doing this? It seems like it'd quickly get out of hand after I got up to like 20 commands.

Perhaps there's a better way to abstract this?

```
 public void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname, String message){

        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase(".np")){
//            TODO: Use Last.fm API to find the now playing
        } else if (message.toLowerCase().startsWith(".register")) {
                cmd.registerLastNick(channel, sender, message);
        } else if (message.toLowerCase().startsWith("give us a countdown")) {
                cmd.countdown(channel, message);
        } else if (message.toLowerCase().startsWith("remember am routine")) {
                cmd.updateAmRoutine(channel, message, sender);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What language, its kind of important at this level of detail.

Comment: @mattnz anyone familiar with Java will recognise it in the code sample he provides.

Comment: @jwenting: It's also valid C# syntax, and I bet there are more languages.

Comment: @phresnel yes, but do those have the exact same standard API for String?

Comment: @jwenting I think you'd have to be familiar with all similar such languages to know for sure. Not everyone capable of a useful answer, or of benefiting from the question, will be a polyglot that can know from a quick look certainly which it is. With so many look alike languages being invented and becoming prominent, this will only get harder. And in comments for various answers here people are taken to task for giving language-specific answers when the question doesn't specify.

Comment: @jwenting: Is it relevant? But even if: One can construct valid examples, like for example a Java/C#-Interop Helper Library, or have a look at Java for .net: ikvm.net . The language is always relevant. The questioner may not be looking for specific languages, he/she may have committed syntax errors (accidentally converting Java to C#, e.g.), new languages may arise (or have risen out the in the wild, where there be dragons) -- edit: My previous comments were to dicky, sorry.

Comment: It could totally be C++ if someone wrote those function names. Having not seen Java, I would not recognize it as Java, and could easily think it was C++.

Comment: This is Java. Sorry guys.

Comment: 1. Switch your project to a functional language, 2. Use a matcher. No, I'm not a rabid functional groupie, and I program C# for a living. But every time I come across this really common pattern, I have "if only this were a Scala project" background thoughts floating through my mind.

Comment: It is not legal c# syntax - the methods would be capitalized, e.g. .StartsWith() .ToLower()

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use a [**dispatch table**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table). This is a table containing pairs ("message part", `pointer-to-function`).  The dispatcher then will look like this (in pseudo code):

```
for each (row in dispatchTable)
{
    if(message.toLowerCase().startsWith(row.messagePart))
    {
         row.theFunction(message);
         break;
    }
}
```

(the `equalsIgnoreCase` can be handled as a special case somewhere before, or if you have many of those tests, with a second dispatch table).

Of course, what `pointer-to-function` has to look like depends on your programming language. [Here](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/courses/cs200/dispatch.html) is an example in C or C++. In Java or C# you will probably use lambda expressions for that purpose, or you simulate "pointer-to-functions" by using the command pattern. The free online book "[Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/)" has a complete chapter about dispatch tables using Perl.

Comment: Can combine that with the command pattern mentioned by others to nicely encapsulate the actual work being done, and maybe use a database or other external resource to configure the table.

Comment: The problem with this, though, is that you won't be able to control the matching mechanism. In OP's example, he uses `equalsIgnoreCase` for "now playing" but `toLowerCase().startsWith` for the others.

Comment: @mrjink: I don't see this as a "problem", it is only a different approach with different pros and cons. The "pro" of your solution: individual Commands can have individual matching mechanisms. The "pro" of mine: the Commands do not have to provide their own matching mechanism. The OP has to decide which solution suits him best. By the way, I also upvoted your answer.

Comment: @DocBrown I agree, and it's a good solution, so I up voted yours as well.

Comment: FYI - "Pointer to function" is a C# language feature called delegates. Lambda is more of an expression object that can be passed around - you can't "call" a lambda like you can call a delegate.

Comment: This seems like an awesome way to handle it as I'm familiar with C++, but unfortunately I'm using Java and don't really understand how I would use lambda expressions to implement this. Can anybody clarify? @user1068 seems to suggest we can't use lambda expressions for this.

Comment: Hoist the `toLowerCase` operation out of the loop.

Comment: @HarrisonNguyen: I recommend http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html . But if you are not using Java 8, you can just use mrink's interface definition without the "matches" part, that's 100% equivalent (that is what I meant by "simulate pointer-to-function by using the command pattern). And user1068's comment is just a remark about the different terms for different variants of the same concept in different programming languages.

Comment: @DocBrown I disagree.  Removing things from inside the loop that don't need to be there would make the structure of your answer clearer.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that, it depends on how complicated your functions really are. If they can be reduced to an expression, then you could use lambdas. But please pay attention, I'm talkin C# stuff there.

Answer (score 31):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
public interface Command {
  boolean matches(String message);

  void execute(String channel, String sender, String login,
               String hostname, String message);
}
```

Then you can have every command implement this interface, and return true when it matches the message.

```
List<Command> activeCommands = new ArrayList<>();
activeCommands.add(new LastFMCommand());
activeCommands.add(new RegisterLastNickCommand());
// etc.

for (Command command : activeCommands) {
    if (command.matches(message)) {
        command.execute(channel, sender, login, hostname, message);
        break; // handle the first matching command only
    }
}
```

Comment: If messages never need to be parsed elsewhere (I assumed that in my answer) this is indeed preferable to my solution for `Command` is more self-contained if it knows when to be called itself. It does produce a slight overhead if the list of commands is huge but that's probably negligible.

Comment: This pattern tends to fit the console command paradygm nicely, but only because it neatly separates the command logic from the event bus and because new commands are likely to be added in the future.   I think it should be noted that this isn't a solution for any circumstance where you have a long chain of if...elseif

Comment: +1 for using a "light" Command pattern! It should be noted that when you're dealing with non-Strings you can make use of e.g. intelligent enums that know how to execute their logic. This even saves you the for-loop.

Comment: Rather than the loop, we could use this as a map if you make Command an abstract class that overrides `equals` and `hashCode` to be the same as the string that represents the command

Comment: This is awesome and easy to understand. Thanks for the suggestion. It's pretty much exactly what I was looking for and seems to be manageable for future addition of commands.

Answer (score 15):

You are using Java - so make it beautiful ;-)

I would probably do this using Annotations:

1. Create a custom Method Annotation

   ```
   @IRCCommand( String command, boolean perfectmatch = false )
   ```
2. Add the Annotation to all relevant Methods in the Class e.g.

   ```
   @IRCCommand( command = ".np", perfectmatch = true )
   doNP( ... )
   ```
3. In your constructor use Reflections to create an HashMap of Methods from all annotated Methods in your class:

   ```
   ...
   for (Method m : getDeclaredMethods()) {
   if ( isAnnotationPresent... ) {
       commandList.put(m.getAnnotation(...), m);
       ...
   ```
4. In your `onMessage` Method, just do a loop over `commandList` trying to match the String on each one and calling `method.invoke()` where it fits.

   ```
   for ( @IRCCommand a : commanMap.keyList() ) {
       if ( cmd.equalsIgnoreCase( a.command )
            || ( cmd.startsWith( a.command ) && !a.perfectMatch ) {
           commandMap.get( a ).invoke( this, cmd );
   ```

Comment: It's not clear that he's using Java, though that is an elegant solution.

Comment: You're right - the code just looked so much like eclipse-auto-formatted Java-Code... But you could do the same with C# and with C++ you could simulate annotations with some clever Macros

Comment: It could very well be Java, however in the future, I suggest that you avoid language-specific solutions if language is not clearly indicated.  Just friendly advice.

Comment: Thanks for this solution - you were right that I'm using Java in the code provided even though I didn't specify, this look really nice and I'll be sure to give it a shot. Sorry I can't pick two best answers!

Answer (score 5):

What if you define an interface, say `IChatBehaviour` which has one method called `Execute` which takes in a `message` and a `cmd` object:

```
public Interface IChatBehaviour
{
    public void execute(String message, CMD cmd);
}
```

In your code, you then implement this interface and define the behaviours you want:

```
public class RegisterLastNick implements IChatBehaviour
{
    public void execute(String message, CMD cmd)
    {
        if (message.toLowerCase().startsWith(".register"))
        {
            cmd.registerLastNick(channel, sender, message);
        }
    }
}
```

And so on for the rest.

In your main class, you then have a list of *behaviours* (`List<IChatBehaviour>`)which your IRC bot implements. You could then replace your `if` statements with something like this:

```
for(IChatBehaviour behaviour : this.behaviours)
{
    behaviour.execute(message, cmd);
}
```

The above should reduce the amount of code you have. The above approach would also allow you to supply additional behaviours to your bot class without modifying the bot class itself (as per the [`Strategy Design Pattern`](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html)).

If you want only one behaviour to fire at any one time, you can change the signature of the `execute` method to yield `true` (the behaviour has fired) or `false` (the behaviour did not fire) and replace the above loop with something like this:

```
for(IChatBehaviour behaviour : this.behaviours)
{
    if(behaviour.execute(message, cmd))
    { 
         break;
    }
}
```

The above would be more tedious to implement and initialize since you need to create and pass all the extra classes, however, it should make your bot easily extensible and modifiable since all your behaviour classes will be encapsulated and *hopefully* independent from each other.

Comment: Where did the `if`s go?  I.e., how do you decide a behavior is executed for a command?

Comment: @mrjink: Sorry my bad. The decision of whether to execute or not is delegated to the behaviour (I mistakenly omitted the `if` part in the behaviour).

Comment: I think I prefer the check about whether a given `IChatBehaviour` can handle a given command, since it allows the caller to do more with it, like processing errors if no command matches, though it is really only a personal preference.  If that isn't needed, then no point needlessly complicating code.

Comment: you'd still need a way to generate the instance of the correct class in order to execute it, which would still have the same long chain of ifs or massive switch statement...

Answer (score 1):

"Intelligent" can be (at least) three things:

#### Higher Performance

The Dispatch Table (and its equivalents) suggestion is a good one. Such a table was called "CADET" in years past for "Can't Add; Doesn't Even Try." However, consider a comment to aid a novice maintainer on just how to manage said table.

#### Maintainability

"Make it beautiful" is no idle admonition.

and, often overlooked...

#### Resiliency

The use of toLowerCase has pitfalls in that some text in some languages must undergo painful restructuring when changing between magiscule and miniscule. Unfortunately, the same pitfalls exist for toUpperCase. Just be aware.

Answer (score 0):

You could have all commands implement the same interface. Then a message parser could return you the appropriate command which you'll only execute.

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute(String channel, String message, String sender) throws Exception;
}

public class MessageParser {
    public Command parseCommandFromMessage(String message) {
        // TODO Put your if/switch or something more clever here
        // e.g. return new CountdownCommand();
    }
}

public class Whatever {
    public void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname, String message) {
        Command c = new MessageParser().parseCommandFromMessage(message);
        c.execute(channel, message, sender);
    }
}
```

It looks like just more code. Yes, you still need to parse the message in order to know which command to execute but now it's at a properly defined point. It may be reused elsewhere. (You might want to inject the MessageParser but that's another matter. Also, the [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) might be a good idea for the commands, depending on how many you expect to be created.)

Comment: I think this is good for decoupling and program organization, though I don't think this directly addresses the problem with having too many if...elseif statements.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is this:

1. Group the commands you have into groups. (you have at least 20 right now)
2. At first level, categorize by group, so you have user name related command, song commands, count commands, etc.
3. Then you go in each group's method, this time you will get the original command.

This will make this more manageable. More benefit when the number of 'else if' grows too much.

Of course, sometimes having these 'if else' wouldn't be a big problem.
I don't think 20 is that bad.